# Wanted: A neat way to clone table rows with GUID primary key column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, replication

I need to clone table rows but am struggling with this syntax. My train of thought went like this:

```
DECLARE @myPk Uniqueidentifier
SET @myPK = NewID()

INSERT INTO my.table (pk, fullname, two, three)
SELECT (@myPK, "Clone of " + fullname , two, three) FROM my.table where pk= @pk
```

but of course the syntax is incorrect. I've also tried

```
INSERT INTO my.table (pk, fullname, two, three)
SELECT (@myPK = newId(), "Clone of " + fullname , two, three) FROM my.table where pk= @pk
```

(I hope you can see where I'm trying to go :-/)

Short of declaring variables for each table column  (not practical due to high number of columns) or using #tempTables (not permitted in this code shop) is there a neat syntax for doing this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't enclose your `SELECT`ed fields in parentheses.**

Try:

```
INSERT INTO my.table (pk, fullname, two, three)
SELECT @myPK, 
       "Clone of " + fullname , 
       two, 
       three 
FROM my.table
where pk= @pk
```

When you enclose everything in parentheses in a `SELECT` statement the engine tries to make that one value, which is not possible.

For instance, try `SELECT (1,2,3)` which will throw a syntax error also, while `SELECT 1,2,3` works fine.

Comment: **Moderator Note** _Comments have been purged from this answer, because they degenerated into noise. Please keep comments constructive, professional and on topic._

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO my.table (pk, fullname, two, three)
SELECT newid() as pk, ('Clone of ' + fullname) as fullname, two, three
FROM my.table where pk= @pk
```

Comment: Also, I was wrong in my assumption that the column names must match, so my answer is redundand to yours

Comment: @Zruty - field names don't matter in the `SELECT` portion of the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: However in a long complicated insert with many fields, I find it helpful to alias to what the final field name will be, makes it easier to troubleshoot.